# Muitiple Data (get) VALUES

Tags: php, laravel, bootstrap-4, controller

need to put one more element to show in controller laravel, today 'status_viagem','=','VIAGEM' works finne but need´s 'VIAGEM' and 'DESCARGA'.

My controller:

```
public function listaPainel(Request $request)
{
    $lista = Cco::where('status_viagem','=','VIAGEM')->get();
    $data['lista'] = $lista; 
    return view('rast.lista_painel', $data);
}
```

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#additional-where-clauses

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your question is not clear. I am guessing you want to compare with more data in where condition. In this case, you may need like this:

```
$lista = Cco::whereIn('status_viagem', ['VIAGEM', 'DESCARGA'])->get();
```

You need to be more clear about your problem.

Comment: Not all questions should be answered. Questions that are not clear fall into that category, and should be flagged/voted for closure.